# Why can I shadow a variable which has been borrowed before? Where is the owner?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership, shadowing, ownership-semantics

Trying to understand ownership and borrowing in Rust, I came across this scenario, where I create an object `a` (which should be the owner) and then borrow it into `b`. Then, I try to shadow `a`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Struct1;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Struct2;

fn main() {
    let a = Struct1;
    let b = &a;

    let a = Struct2;
    
    println!("{:?} {:?}", a, b);
}
```

The problem is, I expected this to fail, but it does in fact work, with the output:

```
Struct2 Struct1
```

If I shadow `a`, where is the owner of the borrowed `b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `a` is still the owner of the `Struct1`, with a lifetime up until the last use within main, which is when the borrow ends when `b` is dropped after the `println!`. Shadowing creates a new binding that does not effect the previous one, other than making it invisible within the current scope.

As such this program is equivalent to (and just syntactic sugar for) a program:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Struct1;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Struct2;

fn main() {
    let a_1 = Struct1;
    let b = &a_1;

    let a_2 = Struct2;
    
    println!("{:?} {:?}", a_2, b);
}
```

where `a_1` is not directly interacted with after the binding of `a_2`.

Answer (score 2):

The owner of `Struct1` is still the first `a` variable you created. The fact that you declared another variable which has the same name does not make a difference with respect to ownership, it only makes a difference at the syntax level in that `a` will refer to something else from that point on.